# Load specific class of jar folder

Tags: java, jar

I have a server who scan a folder containing some jars, and for each jar get class who is subclass of AbstractPlugin class.

I use this jar to help me : https://code.google.com/p/reflections
But when I migrate from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
```

to :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

This code doesn't work anymore :

```
        File pluginFolder = new File(PROP.getString("plugin.folder", "./plugins/"));

        for (File file : pluginFolder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                List<URL> jarsUrl = new ArrayList<>();
                URL jarUrl = file.toURL();
                jarsUrl.add(jarUrl);

                ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                    jarsUrl.toArray(new URL[] {}), 
                    getClass().getClassLoader()
                );

                Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                    ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(loader),
                    new SubTypesScanner()
                );

                Store store = reflections.getStore();
                Set<String> pluginClass = store.getSubTypesOf(AbstractPlugin.class.getName());
            }
        }
```

Before migrate pluginClass respond me with all class who herited from AbstractPlugin in the jar of "plugins" folder.

So I try with a new code to do the same thing :

```
        File pluginFolder = new File(PROP.getString("plugin.folder", "./plugins/"));

        Arrays.asList(pluginFolder.listFiles())
            .stream()
            .filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith(".jar"))
            .forEach((file) -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println(file.getName());

                    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                        new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .addUrls(file.toURI().toURL())
                            .addScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false))
                    );

                    System.out.println(reflections.getAllTypes());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            });
```

It doesn't work too. Someone can help me to fix this and get allsubtype of AbstractPlugin class for each jar in a folder?

Thank you by advance :-)

Comment: What does "This code doesn't work anymore" mean? Is it returning null or do you have some kind of error message?

Comment: Do not return the subclass of AbstractPlugin like in when i'm with reflection old version. No error message just doesn't "scan"